# Magento Contact Form - Success but not receive - Same Domain

Tags: magento, contact-form

I am running Magento 1.9.1.0

Suppose that my web domain is www.aaaaa.com
When I set "Send Emails To" as support@aaaaa.com at "System> Configuration> General> Contacts", the contact form returns a success message but nothing is actually sent to my email (support@aaaaa.com)

However, When I set it to a different domain, e.g. support@bbbbb.com, the contact form returns the same success message and this time the email is received correctly at support@bbbbb.com

How do I fix this issue? I wish to use the same domain. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set cron job , take a look for cron job

[Magento 1.9.1. Emails via CRON job](http://jakesharp.co/magento/magento-emails-not-sent/)

if your theme RWD than change this in contact file

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl(); ?>contacts/index/post/" id="contactForm" method="post">
```